# Converting this SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have the following SQL statement to be converted into LINQ in C#. The `@amount` variable will be a C# variable.

```
DECLARE @amount DECIMAL(20,2)
SET @amount = 120.30

UPDATE INVOICES SET AmtPaid = AmtPaid + @amount WHERE InvoiceNum = 'AC0000034550'
```

Comment: Are you using linq to SQL or entity framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you make a select with linq an then iterate over the list and update the variable??

Answer (score 3):

You *cannot* `UPDATE` with LINQ.

LINQ is a *query* engine, suitable for `SELECT` (if we talk in terms of raw SQL).

Plus, if you already have good working SQL code, *it does not make any sense* to convert it into LINQ; SQL is faster, and works.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ does not do updates,so you cannot convert the SQL to LINQ

Answer (score 0):

I did as follows. Not sure whether it is correct or not:

```
using (var dataContext = GetDataContext())
{
    var invoiceData = from i in dataContext.Invoices
                      where i.InvoiceNumber == paymentData.InvoiceNumber
                      select i;
    foreach(var invoice in invoiceData)
    {
        decimal outPut;
        if (Decimal.TryParse(paymentData.AmountPaid, out outPut))
        {
            invoice.AmtPaid = invoice.AmtPaid + Convert.ToDecimal(paymentData.AmountPaid);
        }
    }
    dataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```